# Convert Bash Install script to Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following bash script below and would like to convert it over to Python and eventually add error handling.

I tried to do arrays and read them in like in bash but i could not find an easy way in Python. Any ideas please?

```
#!/bin/bash
repos=("BloodHoundAD/BloodHound.git" "GhostPack/Seatbelt.git" "GhostPack/SharpUp.git" "yeyintminthuhtut/Awesome-Red-Teaming.git"
"byt3bl33d3r/DeathStar.git" "byt3bl33d3r/CrackMapExec.git" "Cn33liz/p0wnedShell.git" "EmpireProject/Empire.git"
"danielmiessler/SecLists.git" "laramies/theHarvester.git")
for i in "${repos[@]}"; do
  git clone http://github.com/$i
done
echo "There are ${#repos[@]} repos here"
```

Thanks to the great help by the users below:

My updated code in Python is below. Hope it helps someone

```
import os
import subprocess

repos=["BloodHoundAD/BloodHound.git", "GhostPack/Seatbelt.git", "GhostPack/SharpUp.git", "yeyintminthuhtut/Awesome-Red-Teaming.git",
"byt3bl33d3r/DeathStar.git", "byt3bl33d3r/CrackMapExec.git", "Cn33liz/p0wnedShell.git", "EmpireProject/Empire.git",
"danielmiessler/SecLists.git", "laramies/theHarvester.git"]

for repo in repos:
    subprocess.Popen("git clone https://github.com/{}".format(repo) , shell=True).wait()

print ("There are {} repos in the array.".format(str(len(repos))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we covert `repos` into a python list. So:

```
repos=["BloodHoundAD/BloodHound.git", "GhostPack/Seatbelt.git", "GhostPack/SharpUp.git", "yeyintminthuhtut/Awesome-Red-Teaming.git",
"byt3bl33d3r/DeathStar.git", "byt3bl33d3r/CrackMapExec.git", "Cn33liz/p0wnedShell.git", "EmpireProject/Empire.git",
"danielmiessler/SecLists.git", "laramies/theHarvester.git"]
```

Then, we create a for loop in python. In that for loop, we run `git clone package`. Instead of using a library, we can just run it through `os.system()`.

Therefore, the for loop code is:

```
for repo in repos:
    os.system("git clone http://github.com/{}".format(repo))
```

Finally, we get the amount of repos in the list and print it out, which we do with `print ("There are {} repos.".format(str(len(repos))))`

The full code is:

```
import os

repos=["BloodHoundAD/BloodHound.git", "GhostPack/Seatbelt.git", "GhostPack/SharpUp.git", "yeyintminthuhtut/Awesome-Red-Teaming.git",
"byt3bl33d3r/DeathStar.git", "byt3bl33d3r/CrackMapExec.git", "Cn33liz/p0wnedShell.git", "EmpireProject/Empire.git",
"danielmiessler/SecLists.git", "laramies/theHarvester.git"]

for repo in repos:
    os.system("git clone http://github.com/{}".format(repo))


print ("There are {} repos.".format(str(len(repos))))
```

Comment: I don't think the conversion to string is necessary for the string format. Also, `subprocess` should be preferred over `os.system`.

Comment: Do you know what the proper way to use subprocess with the repos array list would be ?